# How do you build the equivalent of an English noun phrase in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, phrases

For example, if I wanted to say "the fear of drowning" or "the desire to do something" in Japanese, how would I do that?

> 溺れるという恐怖？ 何かしたいという気持ち？

These two sentences sound correct to me (please feel free to say otherwise) but is there a way that may sound more natural and shorter?

Comment: "the fear **of** drowning" and "the desire **to do** something" (btw "the desire of doing something" is not correct English and I have fixed it for you) are both noun phrases, not prepositional phrases

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got one wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Japanese.

It sounds perfectly correct to me too.

But you can omit the word "という".

The following phrases sound correct too.

- 溺れる恐怖
- 何かしたい気持ち

## feeling but digress

Strictly speaking, "desire" is often translated as "欲求", "欲望" and things like that.[ref](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/desire)

These are little stronger than "気持ち".

Comment: 解答ありがとうございました！

Comment: I think it can be simpler... A of B is just BのA, so 溺水の恐怖, and the desire to do X is just Xする気分, so 何する気分, or even 何の気分 would be ok.